# Is there anyway to stop the pageload from the browser?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'win32ole'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
driver.get "https://prod.example.com/"
link_name = wait.until {

    element = driver.find_element(:link_text, "Company")
    element if element.displayed?
}

link_name.click if link_name
```

But as the page load is not completed my script got failed everytime producing the below error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout:
:Error (Timeout::Error)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_r
equest'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:615:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:593:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:561:in `find_element_by'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:42:in `find_element'
        from C:/Documents and Settings/rakshiar/My Documents/userdata/Ruby/Scrip
ts/answerlist.rb:29:in `rescue in <main>'
        from C:/Documents and Settings/rakshiar/My Documents/userdata/Ruby/Scrip
ts/answerlist.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

Thus I am looking for to stop the page load after say 20 seconds, and then hit the element as I put in the above code. Becuase I checked when the page is started loading if I try to see the page source,I am not getting any web element. But after the start of page loading if I closed it from start to 10-12 seconds, and try to see the webpage sourece code, all the the required elements there.

So I want to do the same progamatically. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Don't add comments asking if people can help you. If someone has an answer they'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium2 API, On default there is no option to stop the page loading. It will wait for up to the page finishes the loading.

**Try this code:**

```
  driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The above code will wait up to 10 seconds for page loading. If the page loading exits the time it will throw the `TimeoutException`.  You catch the exception and do your needs. I am not sure weather it quits the page loading after the exception thrown. i didn't try this code yet. Want jsut try it.

For more [info.](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html)

Comment: Yes,I tried the same also,But couldn't handle that error. I put there `begin..rescue.. end`. But also got above error. So could you give a dummy code above handling? And also this is ruby version I tried - `driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 180`